# passing relu function to all element of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to pass a relu function to each individual element of a numpy array, when I try it with a sigmoid function, it works but with the relu function, it returns:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

relu function:

```
def relu(x):
    return max(0, x)
```

sigmoid function:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
```

I tried doing relu(myArray) but it returns the valueError, same with map(relu, myArray)

it works fine with sigmoid function, why is it doing that and how can I fix it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `numpy.maximum`. The regular built-in `max` doesn't broadcast over array inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
result = map(relu, array)
```

to apply your function to every element of the array.

```
    import numpy as np

    def relu(x):
        return max(0, x)

    array = np.arange(-10,10)


    result = map(relu, array)
    print(result)
```

Works for me.

Comment: if you check at the second last sentence of my question, I state that doing this returns the same error

Comment: I just edited my answer. Can you maybe provide me with a bit more of your code if you need more help? :)

Comment: You could show me what your array looks like, for example.

Comment: np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)) this is basicaly what it would look like, the answer above yours fixed my problem but thanks for your concern!

Comment: Just so you have a bit more insight into why this did solve your problem, your reshape transforms the array into an array of arrays. You would have needed something like : `result = map(lambda x : map(relu, x), array)` if you wanted to use your function. The other solution is more elegant and more performant though for this case. :)